# Mock a method from another class called from a mocked method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

We are creating unit tests for an application and ran into a problem creating certain tests.

We are unit testing the following Handle() method of the class ActivateCommandHandler:

```
    public class ActivateCommand : IRequest<HttpResponseMessage>
    {
        public string Controller { get; set; }

        public ActivateCommand(string controllername)
        {
            this.Controller = controllername;
        }
    }

    public class ActivateCommandHandler : CommandHandler<ActivateCommand, HttpResponseMessage>
    {
        protected readonly ICommandsGateway _commandsGateway;
        protected readonly EndpointSettings _endpoints;
        protected readonly IUserProfile _userprofile;

        public ActivateCommandHandler(IMediator mediator, ICommandsGateway commandsGateway, IOptions<EndpointSettings> endpoints, IValidationContext validationContext, IUserProfile currentUser) : base(mediator, validationContext, currentUser)
        {
            _commandsGateway = commandsGateway;
            _endpoints = endpoints.Value;
            _userprofile = currentUser;
        }


        public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Handle(ActivateCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (_endpoints.EndpointExists(command.Controller))
            {
                // Check whether the second server controller is deactivated
                string peercontroller = _endpoints.GetPeerController(command.Controller);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(peercontroller))
                {
                    BaseRedundancySwitchStatus controllerStatus = await _commandsGateway.GetRedundancySwitchStatus(_endpoints.GetEndpointAddress(peercontroller));

                    if ((controllerStatus.CurrentState == "Activated") || (controllerStatus.CurrentState == "ActivatedWithWarning") || (controllerStatus.CurrentState == "Activating"))
                    {
                        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                        {
                            Content = new StringContent($"{peercontroller},{controllerStatus.CurrentState}")
                        };

                        return resp;
                    }
                }

                var result = await _commandsGateway.PostActivateCommand(_endpoints.GetEndpointAddress(command.Controller));

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidControllerNameException($"ERROR: The controller {command.Controller} does not exist as an endpoint on this Control Center!");
            }
        }
    }
```

For this the following were mocked: _endpoints, command and _commandsGateway (interface). This works great for unit testing the parameter validation. But we now want to test the behaviour when the peercontroller status is set to a specific value.

To do this we are trying to mock out the function _commandsGateway.GetRedundancySwitchStatus(). The following is the actual test implementation. We mock the _commandsGateway.GetRedundancySwitchStatus() function to return the expected BaseRedundancySwitchStatus with CurrentState set to "Activated". After that we call the handler of the actual function to be tested and check whether we get the expected error.

```
[Fact]
        public async void ShouldHaveErrors_PeerControllerStateActivated()
        {
            var command = new ActivateCommand("Server Controller Slave1");

            BaseRedundancySwitchStatus result = new BaseRedundancySwitchStatus()
            {
                CurrentState = "Activated"
            };

            _commandsGateway
                .Setup(s => s.GetRedundancySwitchStatus("Server Controller Slave1"))
                .ReturnsAsync(result);

            HttpResponseMessage res = await _handler.Handle(command, CancellationToken.None);

            Assert.True(res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
        }
```

Debugging the code, when I step through the code in the Handle() method where _commandsGateway.GetRedundancySwitchStatus is called, I can see that _endpoints.GetEndpointAddress(command.Controller) (which is the parameter) is called and the correct value is returned. After this the debugger steps to the next line without any indication of having executed the mock GetRedundancySwitchStatus() function. Inspecting the controllerStatus variable the value is null. I would expect the value to be the BaseRedundancySwitchStatus object which is supposed to be returned by the mocked GetRedundancySwitchStatus() function.

Where are we going wrong?

Comment: For the later case, how are you mocking `_endpoints.GetEndpointAddress(peercontroller)` method? I believe, it should be returning a different value that's why `_commandsGateway.Setup(s => s.GetRedundancySwitchStatus("Server Controller Slave1")).ReturnsAsync(result);` is not hit. If you make the mock `_endpoints.GetEndpointAddress(peercontroller)` to return `Server Controller Slave1` then things should work as you expect.

Comment: No, wrong. In the test function a variable (result) of type BaseRedundancySwitchStatus is created and returned. That is also what is expected where the actual call is made: ```BaseRedundancySwitchStatus controllerStatus = await _commandsGateway.GetRedundancySwitchStatus(_endpoints.GetEndpointAddress(peercontroller));```

Comment: Your mock object doesn't run because the parameter in `Setup` doesn't equal the one in your test, due to being a reference type?